# "Index was out of range" with checkboxlist selected item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

How can I fix this error? If the first item is selected in checkboxlist CBLAdd, this error doesn't happen. If the second, third, etc item is selected (and the first item is not selected), I get an error.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index'

which occurs at this line `If CBLAdd.Items(i).Selected Then` in the code below:

```
Protected Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    If CBLAdd.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To CBLAdd.Items.Count - 1
            If CBLAdd.Items(i).Selected Then
                'Code removed from here - irrelevant to my question
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the *Code removed from there* is *irrelevant to your question*? Are you modifying the collection, maybe?

Comment: Also make sure you have elements in the checkbox and not being manipulated. Something like this would help If (CBLAdd.SelectedIndex >= 0 AND CBLAdd.SelectedIndex <  CBLAdd.Items.Count) Then.....END If

Comment: Show us the "Code removed from here - irrelevant to my question", i think that you modify the items collection

Comment: Is .Selected even valid? I just tried your code and with Option Strict On I get a late binding error. Intellisense only gives `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType` & `ToString` The error I receive if I run it with Option Strict Off is `MissingMemberException` `Public member 'Selected' on type 'String' not found`